# SQLAlchemy changes value after commit

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Seemingly out of nowhere, my Flask app is now inserting the same value for one column in a table in my database no matter what when it had been previously working.

I have a model here:

```
class rma_test_record(db.Model):
    primary_key = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    test_key = db.Column(db.Integer)
    test_result = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    rma_number = db.Column(db.Integer)
    test_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=dt.utcnow)

    def __init__(self, rma_number, test_key, test_result):
        self.test_key = test_key
        self.test_result = test_result
        self.rma_number = rma_number

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.rma_number) + ' - ' + str(self.primary_key) + ' - ' + str(self.test_key) + ' - ' + str(self.test_result)

    def save(self):
        db.session.add( self )
        db.session.commit()
```

and code in my application:

```
new_test = rma_test_record(rma_number=rma_number, test_key=test_key, test_result=test_result)
print(new_test)
new_test.save()
print(new_test)
```

The result of the prints is

```
2203193857 - None - 41 - True
2147483647 - 7484 - 41 - True
```

So it looks like after the record is committed, the number changes and it is always to this same number. I've never seen a problem like this and can't figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the range of your value and the type of the column to which the value is being saved in.

The `rma_number` column has a SQLAlchemy column type of `Integer` but the value you are passing in (which is `2203193857` in this example) is greater than the maximum value of an Integer. As a result, it default to the maximum value it can store `2147483647` (i.e.: 2^31 - 1)

Consider using the `BigInteger` Column type instead, which allows for larger numbers. For more SQLAlchemy column types see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html